# If there is an onto function $f: A\rightarrow B$ how to prove $\#(B)\leq\#(A)$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

If there is a bijection function between two sets, they have the same cardinality. But if this function is onto? I know that a bijection function is an onto function, so for an equal signal, it is immediately defined. But how to prove it could be less too?

Comment: How do you define $\le$ for cardinal numbers?

Comment: Oh, if there is an onto function, so there is a bijection function between a subset of A and B!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
An onto function has a section (thanks to the axiom of choice),i.e. there exists a function $s:B\longrightarrow A$ such that$$f\circ s=\operatorname{id}_B,$$
so that $s$ is one-to-one.

Comment: Because there is a bijection between a subset of A and B!

Comment: The *corollary* is that there"s a bijection between $B$ and its image by $s$. Actually,  we use thatt if a composition of functions is injective, the first one; in the order of composition, is injective.